# ElasticSearch API for user entered boolean/advanced search queries

Tags: api, elasticsearch

In Kibana I'm able to enter queries with AND / OR / NOT / "..." etc, but all examples I can find for the API (Python or NodeJS or .NET) use the Elasticsearch JSON query format to build queries in code. I would like users to be able to enter 'hot AND soup' or '"hot soup" AND cabbage"' etc which are possible in Lucene and Kibana but I cannot find how to use those via the API. I read all SO entries and Elasticsearch docs I could find about the subject but still missed it.

Is it at all possible and if it is, where can I find examples of that? As I cannot find it, it might not be possible at all; I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the language you're programming in, you simply need to use the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) and pass the use input in there.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\"hot soup\" AND cabbage",
      "default_field": "content"
    }
  }
}
```

Beware, though, that the `query_string` query is very sensitive to the syntax, so your users might not enter correct queries. To alleviate that, a more permissive query would be the [`simple_query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! I struggled with this... Any way to search in multiple indexed fields?